# C# string compression

Tags: c#, loops

I need to make a `method` that takes a `string` as a *parameter* and returns a `string` as a *result*;

```
public static string Compress(string test){}
```

Cant really describe with words what this method needs to do, so here's input/output example:

Input parameter: `ssdwwwweehh`

Output result: `s2d1w4e2h1`

What i have tried is this:

```
static string Compression(string test)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {

            
            int counter = 1;
            
            for (int j = i+1; j < test.Length; j++)
            {
                if (test[i] == test[j])
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    i = j-1;
                    break;
                }      
            }

            result += test[helper] + counter.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Result i get is `s2d1w4e2h2h1`.
So i suppose the problem is when my method comes to the end of the given word.
How do i handle/fix this? Also, im open to suggestions on better solutions, since im not sure this is the best way to approach it.

Comment: This is not a code writing service, you need to make an attempt yourself. If you get stuck include your actual code and the probem you're having and I'm sure someone can help out.

Comment: Sorry but this seems a lot like an homework. Without seeing any effort on your part to solve this problem it is not ethical for me to give you an answer.

Comment: Looks like a form of [Run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#:~:text=Run-length%20encoding%20(RLE),that%20contains%20many%20such%20runs.), if you're struggling to find the right term to search on.

Comment: "_Cant really describe with words what this method needs to do_", Try! I swear that the best way to get a working code. 
use a paper and describe the basic. Use multiple input. At the end of the exercise you will have few english sentence that will almost compile as code.

Comment: `Cant really describe with words what this method needs to do` This is **THE** first thing you need to make yourself clear about, you need to clearly understand what you need to do. Without that, any coding is futile.

Comment: What have you tried? You need to first understand what is requested to produce an implementation. Once you understand the problem you can try to implement a solution and make some tests (input - expected output). Then if you still struggle you can post a clear description of the problem and what you have tried.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This was not a homework and there was no reason for it, whoever banned my "Ask question" privilege. All of my other questions are legit. I just forgot to add what i've tried so far to get as close as possible to solution of the problem. Please lift my "Ask question" restriction. PS Edited original post.

Comment: @polkduran I forgot to add what i've tried so far. I did edit the posting but i need someone to Open the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it correct. Had to implement `int helper = i;` due to `i` being lost in **2nd** `for` loop, in `else` statement.

Answer:

```
static string Compression(string test)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {

                int helper = i;
                int counter = 1;
                
                for (int j = i+1; j < test.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (test[i] == test[j])
                    {
                        counter++;
                        if(j == test.Length - 1)
                        {
                            return result += test[helper] + counter.ToString();
                        }  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = j-1;
                        break;
                    }      
                }

                result += test[helper] + counter.ToString();
            }

            return result;
        }
```